# Android WebKit live video streaming through asf file

Tags: android, webkit, media-player, windows-media-player, asf

I have google around and found that Android's media player doesn't support asf. But the built in player of Google Chrome supports asf streaming. Will the WebKit's media player do that too? Can I use webkit's media player in my application to play live streaming??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier solution is YourMuze FM. YourMuze FM does not provide any content. All they do is simply convert internet radio streams to formats that are suitable for mobile phones.
On your desktop computer, go to Welcome to YourMuze ! | YourMuze Set up a free account. Search for the station you want to listen to. Most popular stations are already on there. If you find your station, save it as a favorite. If you don't find your station, and you know the station's stream url, Find "add a new station" from the main YourMuze page to enter the stream url. The instructions on how to find a stream url are also on that page. http://www.yourmuze.fm/new_station
So, once you have all your favorite stations saved to My Stations, you go to the YourMuze FM mobile site on your phone. m.yourmuze.fm
Log in with the info from the YourMuze fm account you just created and you'll see your My Stations list. Note, you cannot add favorites to My Stations from the mobile site, so make sure to do it on your desktop.
Click the link for one of your stations and you should be playing the station in a few moments. For me the stream comes over the native Android Video player, which is odd, but hey it works. If it's not working for you, you might need to download the free version of either StreamFurious or DroidLive from Android Market to make it work, but it will work.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out video streaming here though. Most of the players I saw use their own algorithms to convert asf to mp3 or mp4 while streaming in their players. Try doing that if you want a more concrete application of your own.

Comment: found something helpful - http://opencore.net/files/Android_WM_Package.pdf this is exactly what we might be looking for.