# how can I play this video in webview or videoview?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-videoview, windows-media-player, asf

I mean I want to play this url:http://212.175.206.240:80/saat_kulesi?MSWMExt=.asf    in webview or videoview . But I don't play this url.
I try this :

```
   VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.setVideoPath("http://212.175.206.240:80/saat_kulesi?MSWMExt=.asf");

        videoView.start();
```

and I try this too :

```
 WebView wv2 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv2.loadUrl("http://212.175.206.240:80/saat_kulesi?MSWMExt=.asf");

 But two of my method but dont work. How can succeed it ?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643938/android-webkit-live-video-streaming-through-asf-file

Comment: http://www.yourmuze.fm/new_station this dont help me ?